# How to create curved header with react native navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Not sure if I framed my question right, but I want to create view something like this, how would it be possible? By the way the area which is dark has to be white i.e beneath the oval curve. I am using react native navigation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A walk around is adding curved parts on screen container view, not on topbar. I used this approach in one of apps I developed earlier, it works well.

```
<View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:"#fff"}}>
  <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:"green", borderRadius:10}}>
  //Place your components here
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `borderRadius`  css compenent in `<View>` style.

```
<View style={{flex: 1, boderRadius:15}}
...your code
</View>
```